# Calibration curve for mixed model (logistic)

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, bootstrap, resampling, calibration

I did some searching using the CV search function and was unable to locate any information on R packages or general approach to creating a calibration curve with a bootstrapped curve overlay (similar to the rms package by Frank Harrell) but for a mixed logistic model.

Does anyone have any direction or insight for this? Are there pitfalls to be concerned with here?